# Get value based on input in two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array

```
var years = [[-1,"0 years"], [1,"< 1 year"], [2,"1-3 years"], [3,"> 3 years"]];
```

And I want to get the number of years based on user Input, which is `-1,1,2,3` how can I do it in Javascript?

I'm trying using `years[years_input]` but I don't get the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find()` method.

```js
var years = [[-1,"0 years"], [1,"< 1 year"], [2,"1-3 years"], [3,"> 3 years"]];

let input = +prompt('enter the index');
console.log(years.find(x => x[0] === input)[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to get. Basically I need to get "0 years" "< 1 year" based on the input which is -1 or 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, I'll accept your answer in 8 min, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,hope it works

```js
let years = [
  [-1, "0 years"],
  [1, "< 1 year"],
  [2, "1-3 years"],
  [3, "> 3 years"]
];

function getYear(year) {

  return years.find(el => el.indexOf(year) > -1)[1]

}

console.log(getYear(-1))
console.log(getYear(1))
console.log(getYear(2))
console.log(getYear(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the first element of the array (you need to use `find` for edge cases like `-1`):

```js
const years = [[-1,"0 years"], [1,"< 1 year"], [2,"1-3 years"], [3,"> 3 years"]];
const index = 3;
const [, res] = years.find(([n]) => n == index);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm trying to get. Basically I need to get "0 years" "< 1 year" based on the input which is -1 or 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: No problem @Radu033, always glad to help.

Comment: @JackBashford This won't work when the input is -1.

Comment: Fixed @Kobe, any better?

Comment: @JackBashford sorted mate 

Comment: Why destructuring  assignment in find function ,considering only zero index ??,can you pls explain a bit what you did in find function?

Comment: @Shubh because we want the second item - it's a 2d Array

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes:

```js
var years = [[-1,"0 years"], [1,"< 1 year"], [2,"1-3 years"], [3,"> 3 years"]];

var input = +prompt()

for(var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  if (years[i].includes(input)) {
  console.log(years[i][1])
  break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and the key for getting the value.

```js
var years = [[-1, "0 years"], [1, "< 1 year"], [2, "1-3 years"], [3, "> 3 years"]],
    yearsMap = new Map(years);

console.log(yearsMap.get(1));
```